# How to save as .nls file in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Just a quick question, how can I "save as" .nls file in netlogo. When I tried to save as from the file menu it save whole program (including main netlogo file). Is there any way I can only save as .nls file???

Answer (score 2):

There are [plans to change that](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/710), but `.nls` support is currently (shall we say) incomplete in NetLogo.

I think that, for now, the easiest way to accomplish what you are trying to do is simply to copy/paste your code in an external editor, save it as `your_file.nls` and then include it with

```
__includes [ "your_file.nls" ]
```

in the NetLogo model you want to use it in.

Comment: It's not absolutely necessary, no. You can always do the dance partly described on [#710](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/710#issue-58398896), where you start by putting the ([recently working](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/717)) `_includes []` string at the top of the code tab, compiling, choosing "New Source File" in the newly appeared "Includes" menu, saving your main model (under a dummy name if needed) and then, in the second "Save" dialog that appears, saving your `.nls` file. I just find all that hard to remember and hard to explain.